# StructureMap to create a Configuration object in c# winforms

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap

Using structuremap and c# 4.0 basically what i have is this:

```
interface IBoard
{
    void Setup();
}

class Board : IBoard
{
    IConfig _config;

    Board(IConfig config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    void Setup()
    {
        //use the _config object here 
    }
}

class Game
{
    IBoard _board;

    Game(IBoard board)
    {
        _board = board;
    }
}

partial class Form1
{
    Form1()
    {
        InitializeForm();
    }

    //in here we need to do some work to setup the IConfig object 
    //via form controls
}

partial class Form2
{
    Game _game;

    Form1(Game game)
    {
        InitializeForm();
        _game = game;
    }
}
```

now under normal usage id just say

```
For<Type>().Use<Class>()
```

or thereabouts for all my dependancies. However what i am after is what is the best pattern to use to set the values of the config object in form1 and then call form2 with the config values set in memory and maintained throughout the app? i thought of using a singleton however the singleton *should* be imuttable or at least be statically created and not accept a parameter based config... so what to do? i currently create the form1 in the Program of the winform start up via

```
ObjectFactory.Get<Form1>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that the IConfig is a good fit for creating using the container since you don't know the parameter values until it's time to instantiate it. I think you have to supply the configuration instance to the code that calls the container in order to fetch the form.

You can supply arguments to the container using the With method:

```
ObjectFactory.With<IConfig>(theConfig).GetInstance<Form2>();
```

You want to minimize calls to the container, preferably just one place in you application that wire up the rest of it during bootstrapping. An alternative is to register a Func, resolve that during bootstrap and use that to create an instance of the Form2.

Registration:

```
var formFactory = config => new Form2(config);
x.For<Func<IConfig, Form2>>().Use( () => formFactory);
```

Usage:

```
//Get the Func somehow, preferably as a ctor dependency in Form1
var form2Creator = ... 
var config = new Config({some parameters from Form1 here});
var form2 = form2Creator(config);
```

Comment: sounds good, this is pretty much what i was looking for... ill give it a whirl and post back

Comment: ive edited your answer to fit a bit but the problem still is that the game object needs to be passed in via form1 ctor (which i thought was unnecessary - please tell me your thoughts on that) and the Game object which has a IConfig object throws and exception because its not being created properly by SM (when i remove it everything works so)

Comment: @AaronHS - please update the question with the needed dependencies for each class and indicate why and when Form1 needs the Game class. Also if you've tried my suggestion please say how you implemented it.

Comment: i did, and someone edited it out. i updated your answer because it was correct but had some missing code, and someone wiped it. awesome work @andomar. @PHeigerg i have accepted your answer but im not re writing the missing code. (there was quite a bit, but in general your answer put me on the right path hence why i am accepting)

Answer (score 0):

If you **register** your `Config` like this:

```
For(Of IConfig).Singleton.Use(Of Config)
```

It'll be **singleton** and **StructureMap** will take care of the rest.

*Another approach is:*

starting a **unit of work** and setting your values, do your job, and dispose UoW, but it's a little **complicated** and I have no idea if you need UoW or not.

Comment: The problem with that approach, if I understand the OP correctly, is that the configuration is created based on arguments only known upon creation (not at the time when the types are registered).

Comment: It's created the first time it's requested from ObjectFactory. By the way, do you really need to create it when your types are registered? If so, leave a comment & I'll update my post.

Comment: In order to create the config you need some data that's not available until the user has input it into Form1 (which is after the registration has occured). This is my view of the OP's question.

Comment: correct PHeidberg. if the config data was static, id just point my containers Use to some concrete class that either loads or contains the data. what i need is the values to be set after the DI container has registered all its mappings